# Where should the 'for' loop be placed for the the error to go away?

Tags: android, flutter, syntax

Before using `ListView.seperator`, the `for` loop didn't cause any problems:

```dart
body: ListView(
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60),
           children: [
             for (var question in questionsList)
               Text(
                 question,
                 textScaleFactor: 1.5,
               ),
           ]
         )
```

Now that it's been switched, I keep getting an error.

```dart
 body: Center(
          
          child: 
            ListView.separated(
              
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { 
                return Container(
                    for (var question in questionsList)
                    alignment: const Alignment(0, .7),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        question,
                        textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
               },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)  => const 
                Divider(color: Colors.black,) 
              ,
              itemCount: questionsList.length
            ),
        ),
```

I've tried moving it to the top of `ListView.seperator` - didn't like that, at the top of `Container()` - didn't like that, within `Padding()` - it didn't like that either.

I want to create a horizontal list, with each question in it's own little box at the bottom of the screen. I want the questions to be looped through from a separate file.

Comment: What error do you get? And why do you use a ListView around your for loop

Comment: What did your code look like before?  It looks like you're trying to use a collection-`for` expression, which would need to go inside of a `List` literal (e.g. `[for (var question in questionsList) ...]`).

Comment: @targiald  This is the error that appears -> `Expected an identifier.dart(missing_identifier)
Expected to find ')'.`   I want ListView to be able to access the items produced from that loop so that those are the items displayed when a person scrolls

Comment: @jamesdlin I am a little confused by your comment... So does that mean that my 'for' loop needs to be encased by brackets?

Comment: @Jaz Yes; there is a `for` *statement* (which cannot be used as an expression), and a `for` *element* that can be used within collection literals.  However, simply adding brackets around your `for` loop won't help you because its body needs to be a expression, and currently what you have makes no sense.  Again, what did your code look like before when it was working?

Comment: Put another way: *what* do you want the result to be?  If you want to create, say, a `List`, then you should use collection-`for`; it goes within brackets because you're creating a `List` literal, and collection-`for` fills in the elements to that `List`.  If you want a `List` of `Widget`s, then the body to that collection-`for` should be a `Widget`.  But simply adding brackets to what you currently have wouldn't make sense either, because `Container([alignment: ..., color: ..., alignment: ..., color: ...])` would be nonsense.

Comment: @jamesdlin This is what the code looked like when it was working `body: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60),
          children: [
            for (var question in questionsList)
            Text(
              question,
              textScaleFactor: 1.5,
            ),   
          ]
        ),` I apologize for the code not being readable due to the comments format!

Comment: @jamesdlin As for what I want the result to be - I was experimenting with creating a separation between each element in the list, hence ***ListView.seperated***. Most of the examples I came across were of lists going vertically instead of horizontally and not looping through a list from a different file as I was. I added the ***Container*** because it allowed me to position the scrollable where I wanted it. The ***Center*** was added because it positioned the list directly in the middle of the screen for me. I just had to adjust it.

Comment: @jamesdlin I am very new to Flutter and am experimenting all the while coding it for work. I hope what I've said above makes sense as I can't put any pictures to show you what I was trying to go for.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop you were using before is called "collection `for`".  It's used within a collection *literal* (that is, within `[]` for a `List` literal, `{}` for `Set` and `Map` literals) to generate elements for the collection.  For more information, I strongly recommend reading [Bob Nystrom's article that introduces them](https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c).

`ListView.separated` doesn't take a `List` of items; it instead uses an `itemBuilder` callback that is expected to return each individual item.  You don't need to use a loop with it because `ListView.separated` is already iterating for you; you just need your callback to return the appropriate element that corresponds to `index`.

This is untested, but you probably want something like:

```dart
body: Center(
          child: 
            ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                    alignment: const Alignment(0, .7),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        questionsList[index], // ***
                        textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)  => const 
                Divider(color: Colors.black) ,
              itemCount: questionsList.length,
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: That makes sense and is something I did not know. I will be reading that article you linked and thank you so much! That did exactly what I was trying to do